# Bayesian Regression Model

Tags: bayesian, regression-coefficients, standard-error, hierarchical-bayesian, bayesian-network

I am new to Bayesian modeling. I am running Bayesian regression model in R using brm function from brms library, which is powered by STAN. I have a data with 10 million records. I took 10% sample out of it so as to run no Prior bayesian on it, and get Betas and est error, which I plan to use as priors for rest of the data. My queries are:

But all the beta estimates (from no prior model run on the 10% data) I am getting are having 0 est. error and non zero coefficent value, hence the beta distribution would be for e.g N(0.7,0) which isnt a distribution. Hence I cant use these results as prior. Below is the function I am using:

```
bmod1 <- brm(
           Y ~ Samp + C_95 + CR_85 + LE+ SPD90 + CPA + FTO,
          data = rawdb4, family = gaussian(),
          warmup = 600, iter = 3000, chains = 4,
          control = list(adapt_delta = 0.98), cores=16, seed=150)


Here rawdb4 is the data with 10%(~100k records) of the overall data. I am not giving any prior value.
```

I have tried multiple itereation with 10%, 20%, 5% data with different number of chains and itereations combinations but the results are almost same. What should be my approach? My objective is to get proper estimates of all the variables and I want to do it with Bayesian regression only as a part of learning.

Am I missing something here? Please suggest. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you please add your code to the question? The phrase "no prior model" is a bit confusing, I am not sure if you mean "non-informative prior" or something else, and I believe that's the source of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Pedro, Thanks for the comment. I have added the codes. Also, by no prior I mean I haven't given prior input to the model.

Comment: Hi Pedro, Thanks for the comment. I have added the codes. Also, by no prior I mean, I haven't given any prior input to the model. Thanks!